# Apache: Redirect a folder with basic auth to secure server

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, https, basic-authentication

In the past, users have logged onto a private folder using Basic HTTP authentication. We have upgraded the site by adding a SSL certificate, so that these users are now encouraged to use SSL in order to secure their passwords.

In an attempt to redirect from http://example.com/private/ to https://example.com/private/, I have tried this .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

AuthUserFile   /usr/home/example/passwd
AuthName       "Private Page"
AuthType       Basic
```

The trouble is that when the users navigate to the non-SSL page, it asks them for their authentication first, before the redirect. This defeats the whole purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can try splitting your rewrite rules and mod_auth instructions:

#### In vhosts you put, this will be done before perdir .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^/?private https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

#### In /private/.htaccess, you have only mod-auth instructions:

```
AuthUserFile   /usr/home/example/passwd
AuthName       "Private Page"
AuthType       Basic
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Apache 2.4 you can avoiding the double authentication using [configuration sections](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/sections.html).

```
# Redirect to HTTPS
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

# Authenticate users only when using HTTPS
<If "%{HTTPS} == 'on'">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Special things"
    AuthUserFile /etc/blah.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
</If>
```